# Got some error when installing Wine

Tags: apt, wine, dpkg

At the WineHQ site I followed the last step to install one of the available packages, I choose the stable branch and the command is `sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-stable`, it unpacking some wine file and end up getting this error:

```
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/wine-stable-amd64_5.0.2~
focal_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './opt/wine-stable/lib64/wine/d3dx9_24.dll' to 
'/opt/wine-stable/lib64/wine/d3dx9_24.dll.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space 
left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
        d
pkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/wine-stable-amd64_5.0.2~focal_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says it so

> failed to write (No space left on device)
> No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error

Check your free space on your main partition, please. Probably you don't have enough space in your partition.

You may simply type `df -h` to terminal to find out.